# Is a representation sphere dualizable inside naive G-spectra?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $G$ act on a vector space $V$.  Let $S(V)$ be the representation sphere.  In the monoidal category of $RO(G)$-graded spectra $S(V)$ is invertible, so it's dualizable too.

Is $S(V)$ dualizable in the monoidal category of naive $G$-spectra?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $G$ be of order $2$, and let $V$ be the nontrivial one-dimensional representation.  I'll write $S(V)$ for the unit sphere in $V$ (which is just $G$); the one-point compactification of $V$ is then the unreduced suspension of $G$, which I'll call $S^V$.  We can only form spectra from $G$-spaces with fixed basepoint, so we need to consider $S(V)_+=G_+$ rather than $S(V)$ itself.  There is a cofibration $G_+\to S^0\to S^V$, and $S^0$ is its own dual, so the question for $S^V$ is equivalent to the question for $G_+$.

In the category of genuine $G$-spectra, $G_+$ is its own dual, which means that there are unit and counit maps $S^0\xrightarrow{\eta}G_+\wedge G_+\xrightarrow{\epsilon}S^0$ making certain diagrams commute.  In the naive category, $\{S^0,G_+\wedge G_+\}^G$ is the colimit of the unstable mapping sets $[S^n,S^n\wedge G_+\wedge G_+]^G$, which are trivial because $S^n\wedge G_+\wedge G_+$ is free away from the basepoint.  Thus, we cannot construct the required map $\eta$, and $G_+$ is not self-dual.  The same applies if we replace one of the $G_+$'s by something else, so $G_+$ is not dualisable.

Comment: Neil, in the naive category don't we have to take a cofibrant replacement of $S^n$ to calculate homotopy classes of maps?

Comment: @Tyler: what foundations do you have in mind?  For finite groups I think we can do something very similar to Boardman's original setup, where a naive $G$-spectrum consists of $G$-CW complexes with equivariant structure maps $\Sigma X_n\to X_{n+1}$.  A genuine $G$-spectrum has $X_n$ defined only when $|G|$ divides $n$, and structure maps $S^{\mathbb{R}[G]}\wedge X_n\to X_{n+|G|}$.  My argument is valid in that context.  With EKMM foundations you would need cofibrant replacement wrt a model structure based on the trivial universe, which would not make a difference at the end of the day.

Comment: Naive Spanier-Whitehead works fine equivariantly and gives the full subcategory of finite G-CW spectra (up to equivalence) in any other good construction.  Neil's answer is fine, with R the regular representation, but  Gaunce's result I cited is valid for orbits of compact Lie groups, not just finite ones. The pre-EKMM Lewis-May foundations work for compact Lie groups and any universe, the suspension G-spectra of spheres with trivial $G$-action are cofibrant there, and space level maps can be used via adjunction. 
Passing to EKMM doesn't clarify things here. 

Comment: @Neil: My apologies.  My comment was based on misinterpreting the question: I was considering a different weak equivalence structure on naive G-spectra (using underlying weak equivalences, rather than equivariant ones).

Comment: @TL: Is that the same as spectra over BG?  In this category the analog of $G_+$ has a dual?

Comment: Just a remark: in the naive category there's another kind of duality which uses $S[G]=$ suspension spectrum of $G_+$ instead of the sphere to dualize with. In this variant $S^0[G]$ (which represents $G_+$ as a stable object) is always self-dual. This is since $F(S^0[G],S^0[G])^G = S^0[G]$, where I've taken equivariant function spectra on the left of the equals sign.

Answer (score 2):

There is a strongly related result of Gaunce Lewis that I would like to advertise.   We have different kinds of $G$-spectra for different ``universes'' $U$, which are countable sums of representations that include $\mathbf{R}$ and countably many copies of each representation they contain.  Naive $G$-spectra are indexed on the trivial universe, genuine ones are indexed on the complete universe, which contains all irreducible representations.  Gaunce proved that the $U$-suspension $G$-spectrum of an orbit $G/H_+$ (I've added a disjoint basepoint) is dualizable if and only if $G/H$ embeds as a sub $G$-space of a representation in the universe $U$. Neil's example is the simplest illustration of this general result. (Tyler, no problem with cofibrancy here: Neil is working in the Spanier-Whitehead category; Gaunce is working with Lewis-May $G$-spectra.)